# JQuery Blur Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm using the following script to blur a box when I click a button, but how can I make the blur take 500ms?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //attach click event to button
  $('.button').click(function(){

    //when button is clicked we call blurElement function
    blurElement("#box", 2);

  });

  //attach click event to button
  $('.button2').click(function(){

    //when button is clicked we disable the blur
    blurElement("#box", 0);

  });


});

//set the css3 blur to an element
function blurElement(element, size){
  var filterVal = 'blur('+size+'px)';
  $(element)
    .css('filter',filterVal)
    .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
    .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
    .css('oFilter',filterVal)
    .css('msFilter',filterVal);
}



</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change your function to this:

```
 function blurElement(element, size) {
    var filterVal = 'blur(' + size + 'px)';
    $(element).css({
        'filter':filterVal,
        'webkitFilter':filterVal,
        'mozFilter':filterVal,
        'oFilter':filterVal,
        'msFilter':filterVal,
        'transition':'all 0.5s ease-out',
        '-webkit-transition':'all 0.5s ease-out',
        '-moz-transition':'all 0.5s ease-out',
        '-o-transition':'all 0.5s ease-out'
    });
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3F6jm/63/)

Comment: I used this one, it was the easiest. Thanks

Comment: Works like a charme!

Answer (score 4):

In the css, give the `#box` a transition:

```
#box{
  filter: blur(0);
 /* and the rest of it */
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition:0.5s;
  -moz-transition:0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I'm with you @BeatAlex... I highly recommend using jQuery simply to add a class to the element on which you want the transition to take place and let CSS do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript setTimeout:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $(element)
          .css('filter',filterVal)
          .css('webkitFilter',filterVal)
          .css('mozFilter',filterVal)
          .css('oFilter',filterVal)
          .css('msFilter',filterVal);
   }, 500);
```

If you were using jquery animations you could use .delay() but it won't work for css which isn't in the animation queue.

Comment: This will not create an animation. It will just blur the element 500ms later

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use CSS3 use the below for either a box or text:

```
#box {
width:100px;
height:100px;
animation-name: blurbox;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-name: blurbox;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
/* Standard syntax */
-moz-animation-name: blurbox;
-moz-animation-duration: 5s;
-o-animation-name: blurbox;
-o-animation-duration: 5s;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurbox {
    0% { background-color:#f00;}
    100% { background-color:#f00; -webkit-filter: blur(50px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes blurbox {
    0% { background-color:#f00;}
    100% { background-color:#f00; -moz-filter: blur(50px); }
}

@keyframes blurbox {
    0% { background-color:#f00; }
    100% { background-color:#f00; filter: blur(50px); }
}


#text {
animation-name: blurtext;
animation-duration: 5s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-name: blurtext;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
/* Standard syntax */
-moz-animation-name: blurtext;
-moz-animation-duration: 5s;
-o-animation-name: blurtext; blurtext;
-o-animation-duration: 5s;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurtext {
    0% { color: #000; }
    100% { text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000; color: transparent; }
}

@-moz-keyframes blurtext {
    0% { color: #000; }
    100% { text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000; color: transparent; }
}

@keyframes blurtext {
    0% { color: #000;}
    100% { text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000; color: transparent; }
}
```