# jquery image blur animation

Tags: jquery, image, animation, blur

I am currently trying to do an image "slider" (I wouldn't say slider, don´t know how to say it in english (I´m german :P)) which includes a blur effect and 3 different images. Everything works fine but the animation. I already checked for similar questions, but nothing what I found seemed to work.
Here is my code:

Jquery

```
function wait(ms){
var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}    

var current = "bg_image_1.jpg";
var current_num = 1;

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(current == "bg_image_3.jpg"){
        $("#changing").css('filter', 'blur(5px)');
        wait(2000);
        $("#changing").attr('src', 'bg_image_1.jpg');
        $("#changing").css('filter', 'blur(0px)');
        current_num -= 2;
    } else {
        current_num += 1;
        current = current.slice(0, 8) +"_"+ current_num + ".jpg";
        $('#changing').css('filter', 'blur(5px)');
        wait(2000);
        $('#changing').attr('src', current);
        $('#changing').css('filter', 'blur(0px)');
    }
}, 10000);
```

CSS

```
#changing {
    filter: blur(0px);
    transition: blur 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: blur 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: blur 2s linear;
}
```

html

```
<div id="bg_image_animated"><img id="changing" src="bg_image_1.jpg" height="800px" width="100%"/></div>
```

It would be cool if some of you who know what is wrong answered, I´ve tried to solve this problem for a couple of hours now. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Blur Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429557/jquery-blur-animation)